# Dynamic boostrap card body + image in Vue js ( firestore cloud DB + local image source )

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4, google-cloud-firestore, axios

I am trying to create a small Vue js page ( `AddItem.vue` ) with below data.

```
  data (){
      dish_name: null,
      dish_description: null,
      dish_type: null,
      dish_image: null
  }
```

I have a bootstrap form to accept above data and invoke a `insertData()` method which calls *Firestore*  `Collection.Add()` method.

```
insertData() {
      db.collection("Items")
        .add({
          dish_type: this.dish_type,
          dish_name: this.dish_name,
          dish_description: this.dish_description,
          dish_image: this.dish_image
        })
        .then(docRef => {
          console.log("Client added: ", docRef.id);
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.error("Error adding dish: ", error);
        });
    }
```

I would like to copy the image being uploaded from form to
`/static/` directory of `vue` with a name,id, actual image . Is there anyway to do this ?

Also, i would like to list all items later as bootstrap cards with card data from firestore and card image from vue/static folder.

Is *Axios JS* - a correct way to PUT and GET images files from `static` folder in Vue ?

Is there any other better way to do this ?

Thank you,

Rahul

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Brad Traversy & Academind, I used axios to put and get images from a node back-end server ( express js ).

A second approach is to store both data + image in firebase firestore. I was not sure of the performance of second approach and hence wanted to store images in server itself.

I could not make out much time difference between two approaches. To complete my project, I have decided to store data + image in firestore and access with firestore API's.

more info on firestore can be found here - https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart